# Proper Windows 8-64 bit driver for Arduino Yún (Yun)

Tags: arduino, usb, driver, windows

I am trying to setup Arduino environment under Windows 8-64bit running on VMWare Fusion 6.0.2 host machine.
I connect the Yun to my windows machine and the device get detected under windows but windows is unable to find proper driver for my Yun Board.

So I have opened the windows device manager to select a proper .inf file for my Yun Arduino.
So I have gone through following steps:

1-Going to Device Manager
2-Selecting OtherDevices (Arduino Yun)
3-Update Driver
4-Browse my computer
5-Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
6-show all devices
7-picking the "arduino.inf"  file that exists in the x86 (32-bit) version of the windows Arduino IDE 1.5.4r2 under drivers folder.
8- Few seconds of progression and then BOD Windows crashes!?! (Error message is BAD_POOL_CALLER)

I can not collect information on the reason of that fatal crash under my virtual machine.

I am wondering is there something wrong with my Win8-64bit machine or there is a problem with its drivers !? smiley-sad-blue

It is noteworthy that in fact I programmed my Yun board in my MAC system via Arduino 1.5.4Beta IDE and it seems it works  perfectly in my MAC system so maybe there is nothing wrong with the Yun board itself.

What is the chipset that is used Yun board for USB communication and the board programming which is attached to board's small micro usb connector? I could download proper drivers from its vendor.

(I have asked a very same question on Arduino.cc but not reply I hope I get an answer here)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **What is the chipset that is used [in the] [Yún] board for USB communication [...] ?**

The Arduino Yún has two USB interfaces:

- A USB interface built in to the ATmega32U4-AU which manages serial comms.
- A USB 2.0 hub based on an AU6350

See [schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Yun-schematic.pdf)

> The ATmega32U4 provides a dedicated UART TTL (5V) serial communication. The 32U4 also allows for serial (CDC) communication over USB and appears as a virtual com port to software on the computer. The chip also acts as a full speed USB 2.0 device, using standard USB COM drivers.

...

> The Yún appears as a generic keyboard and mouse, and can be programmed to control these input devices using the Keyboard and Mouse classes.

See [Arduino Yún](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun)

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I have checked the website of AU6350 and it seems that 
there is no windows driver for it.
I am not sure how can I update the Arduino Yun driver in Windows 8-64bit shall I use generic mouse/keyboard driver instead?

Comment: @Sina: The USB mouse/keyboard "class" is not useful for programming the ATmega32u4. You need the "connected device" class (CDC) for that. As an aside: maybe the VM isn't virtualising the USB interface sufficiently.

Comment: So since I have to run it under VMWare Fusion 6.0.2 it means that I can not get it work under Windows Guest machine? And is there any kind of generic driver for CDC under windows?Thanks

Comment: @Sina: I'd expect it to work with generic drivers. By the way, Win 8 drivers and VMs are somewhat off-topic here. I don't know if superuser.com would be the right place. Is an older Arduino recognised OK? Is a [USB-serial interface cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718) recognised?

Comment: I have tried it on Windows7-32 Bit (As a guest machine of VMWareFusion 6.0.2) and all the drivers that came with the Arduino 1.5.4r2 executables are working well and Yun board is shown as an extra COM port in windows device manager. Once I program the board an extra COM port as YunBootloader shows up and after programming it closes.There is something wrong either with Driver in Win8-64 bit or Windows that fails.